# macOS: A CoreServicesUIAgent Verifying ...dylib Popup keeps popping up every time

Tags: macos, monterey, activity-monitor

A popup keeps popping up every time on my system and looks like this:
[image]

It does not go away when I click on the 'x' and it does not progress. It hinders everything by keeping itself on top of all windows, so, I minimize it and it keeps doing its thing in the background, but I guess at some time, the process fails and the popup comes up again. This has been happening to my system for 3-4 days now.

I also tried too close the whole process from activity monitor and the popup went away, but every now and then, I would see a flicker of a box (the popup) - flashes and immediately goes away until I restart. Once I restart, the permanent popup comes back.

I seriously need a solution for this now. I tried to search for this, but found no solution till now. I am running macOS Monterey v12.3.1 (21E258).

Comment: How did you resolve this?

Comment: Facing the same issue, if anyone is able to resolve it please let me know